# Why this pattern matching fails in Agda?

Tags: unification, agda

Consider function `wa''` (need natural number definition, either in stdlib or `Agda.Builtin.Nat`):

```
postulate comm : ∀ m n -> m + n ≡ n + m

wa'' : ∀ m n -> wa (m + n) ≡ wa (n + m)
wa'' m n with comm n m
...        | refl = { }0
```

The pattern matching on `comm n m` with `refl` fails. But if I add one more match:

```
wa'' : ∀ m n -> wa (m + n) ≡ wa (n + m)
wa'' m n with (n + m) | comm n m
...        | .(m + n) | refl = { }0
```

This code works. Is there any semantics-level difference between these two code snippets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's [desugar the `with`s](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.4.1/language/with-abstraction.html#technical-details).

First definition:

```
wa''-aux : ∀ m n -> n + m ≡ m + n -> wa (m + n) ≡ wa (n + m)
wa''-aux m n refl = ?  -- cannot unify n + m with m + n

wa'' : ∀ m n -> wa (m + n) ≡ wa (n + m)
wa'' m n = wa''-aux m n (comm n m)
```

Second definition:

```
wa''-aux : ∀ m n w -> w ≡ m + n -> wa (m + n) ≡ wa w
wa''-aux m n .(m + n) refl = ?

wa'' : ∀ m n -> wa (m + n) ≡ wa (n + m)
wa'' m n = wa''-aux m n (n + m) (comm n m)
```

When checking that `refl` is a valid case, we must *unify* the two sides of the equation it is supposed to be a proof of. Remember that `refl : {x : ℕ} → x ≡ x`, so we must find a *single* value `x` that is βη-equal to both the left-hand side and right-hand side.

In the first case, this means unifying `n + m` with `m + n`, and in the second case, this means unifying `w` with `m + n`. The latter is obviously possible, where we assign `w ↦ m + n` and note that we have done this with the dot pattern `.(m + n)` in `w`'s place. The former is not obvious. How should we unify `n + m` with `m + n`? `n ↦ m` would be wrong: note, for example, that `2 + 3 ≡ 3 + 2`, but `2` does not unify with `3`.

In general, things are made difficult by the fact that Agda can't show that `_+_` is injective. This is for the good reason that it isn't (as our example showed). Agda can show that constructors are injective, justified by the fact that Agda has no quotient types or the like. This is why `suc m` and `suc n` *will* unify. Agda does not try to show that any defined functions are injective, though it in principle could (by getting the user to supply a proof, for example).

Comment: Thank you! So in Agda, the contextual information (say, which terms are equivalent) doesn't hold across functions. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Like, if a parameter of type $a \equiv b$ is matched as $refl$, $a$ and $b$ will be treated as equivalent in the context. We have to bring this information out of the generated helper function (by introducing an explicit argument whose value is trivially $a$) so that we can make use of it in the proofs.

Comment: From the outside, we only learn about the behaviour of `wa''-aux` when the proof we pass to it is judgmentally `refl`, matching the definition clause. `comm n m` is not judgmentally `refl` – it is an inductive argument. Whenever we do pass in `refl`, we've already done the same unification on the outside as has been done on the inside, so generally, this unification information doesn't leak.